# Linux Install Gcc

Tags: linux, yum, gcc

I am new to linux and I am setting up a Linux-64 bit for programming in C++ and I want to install the gcc.x86_64 and gcc-C++.x86_64. I use command yum install the two packages. However, half way through the installation, I got no mirror found for the packages. What should I do to install it?

It shows

```
Error Downloading Packages:
 glibc-common-2.12.1-4.x86_64: failure: glibc-common-2.12.1-4.x86_64.rpm 
 from updates:[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
 cpp-4.4.4-10.fc13.x86_64: failure: cpp-4.4.4-10.fc13.x86_64.rpm from updates:      [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
 gcc-4.4.4-10.fc13.x86_64: failure: gcc-4.4.4-10.fc13.x86_64.rpm from updates:       [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

Thanks

Comment: Begin with providing full output.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your `yum` database:

```
# yum update
```

See also [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=521358).